# How to copy image from old worksheet into new one

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working with the Apache POI API to split an Excel file with multiple sheets into multiple Excel files, with each file containing only one sheet.
However, it seems that when I attempted to move an image from an old worksheet to a new one, it had no impact; when I opened the excel file, the images should have been displayed, but all I saw was blank images placeholder, as can be seen in the image below.

Here is my code (to copy an image from an old worksheet into a new worksheet):

```
private void copyImage(XSSFSheet srcSheet_, XSSFSheet dstSheet_) {
    XSSFWorkbook srcWorkbook_ = srcSheet_.getWorkbook();
    XSSFWorkbook dstWorkbook_ = dstSheet_.getWorkbook();

    List<POIXMLDocumentPart> pdp = srcWorkbook_.getRelations();
    List<POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart> rels = srcSheet_.getRelationParts();
    XSSFDrawing dg = null;
    for (POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rp : rels) {
        POIXMLDocumentPart r = rp.getDocumentPart();
        if (r instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
            dg = (XSSFDrawing) r;
            continue;
        }
        addRelation(rp, dstSheet_);
    }

    try {
        for (PackageRelationship pr : srcSheet_.getPackagePart().getRelationships()) {
            if (pr.getTargetMode() == TargetMode.EXTERNAL) {
                dstSheet_.getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship(pr.getTargetURI().toASCIIString(), pr.getRelationshipType(), pr.getId());
            }
        }
    } catch (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException e) {
        throw new POIXMLException("Failed to clone sheet", e);
    }

    CTWorksheet ct = dstSheet_.getCTWorksheet();
    if (ct.isSetLegacyDrawing()) {
        log.atWarn().log("Cloning sheets with comments is not yet supported.");
        ct.unsetLegacyDrawing();
    }
    if (ct.isSetPageSetup()) {
        log.atWarn().log("Cloning sheets with page setup is not yet supported.");
        ct.unsetPageSetup();
    }

    dstSheet_.setSelected(false);

    if (dg != null) {
        if (ct.isSetDrawing()) {
            ct.unsetDrawing();
        }
        XSSFDrawing clonedDg = dstSheet_.createDrawingPatriarch();
        // copy drawing contents
        clonedDg.getCTDrawing().set(dg.getCTDrawing().copy());

        XSSFDrawing drawingPatriarch = srcSheet_.getDrawingPatriarch();
        if (drawingPatriarch != null) {
            List<POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart> srcRels = drawingPatriarch.getRelationParts();
            for (POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart rp : srcRels) {
                POIXMLDocumentPart r = rp.getDocumentPart();
                int chartNumber = r.getPackagePart().getPackage().getPartsByContentType(XSSFRelation.CHART.getContentType()).size() + 1;
                int imageNumber = r.getPackagePart().getPackage().getPartsByContentType(XSSFRelation.IMAGE_PNG.getContentType()).size() + 1;
                if (r instanceof XSSFChart) {
                    POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart chartPart = clonedDg.createRelationship(XSSFRelation.CHART, dstWorkbook_.getXssfFactory(), chartNumber, false);
                    XSSFChart chart = chartPart.getDocumentPart();
                    chart.importContent((XSSFChart) r);
                    chart.replaceReferences(dstSheet_);
                }
                else if (r instanceof XSSFPictureData){
                    XSSFPictureData img = r.createRelationship(XSSFRelation.IMAGE_PNG, dstWorkbook_.getXssfFactory(), imageNumber,true).getDocumentPart();
                    try (OutputStream out = img.getPackagePart().getOutputStream()){
                        out.write(((XSSFPictureData) r).getData());
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        throw new POIXMLException(e);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    addRelation(rp, clonedDg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I also do the trick: rename the extension from '.xlsx' to '.zip' and extract it, then compare the original (renamed and extracted) with the new excel file. I found that in the new excel file, the 'media' folder and 'drawings/_rel' folder were not created.

Could you guys help me explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your code seems to be a incomplete copy of the code of [XSSFWorkbook.java:cloneSheet](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_3/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.java?view=markup#l616). Why not simple using `XSSFWorkbook.cloneSheet`? I guess because this clones sheet into the same workbook only. But if that could be simply changed, Apache POI would have done this, no? Copy the source file as much times as you need and then delete not wanted sheets from each copy. After that you have "split an Excel file with multiple sheets into multiple Excel files".

Comment: Thank you for your attention. As you mentioned, I have tried to remove all unnecessary sheets from each new xlsx file, but the problem is that when I write out a new WB (which only contains one sheet), the file size is still the same as the original file. But when I opened it with Microsoft Excel and saved it again, the file size decreased as I expected. I'm using removeSheetAt(index) to remove sheet by sheet, but it looks like it still has some sheet relations or the sheet is only marked as deleted but not completely removed. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: You are correct `Workbook.removeSheetAt` lacks removing the embedded media files when the removed sheet contains a drawing having relations to embedded media files. You could file a bug about this issue here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. This method copies an image located at a certain row and column and pastes it into a different excel file that has the same worksheet name. Of course it can be modified to your specific needs.

```
public void copyCellPicturesFromXLSX1_toXLSX2(String srcFilePath, String dstFilePath, String sheetName, int srcRowNum, int colNum, int dstRowNum)
{
    try {
        Workbook srcWB = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(srcFilePath));
        Workbook dstWB = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(dstFilePath));
        Sheet srcSH = srcWB.getSheet(sheetName);
        Sheet dstSH = dstWB.getSheet(sheetName);
        Drawing srcdraw = srcSH.createDrawingPatriarch();
        Drawing dstdraw = dstSH.createDrawingPatriarch();
        List<Picture> pics = new ArrayList<Picture>();
        int pictureIdx, row, col;
        if (srcdraw instanceof HSSFPatriarch) 
        {
            HSSFPatriarch hp = (HSSFPatriarch)srcdraw;
            for (HSSFShape hs : hp.getChildren()) 
            {
                if (hs instanceof Picture)  
                {
                    System.out.println("Picture found in HSSF");
                    pics.add((Picture)hs);
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            XSSFDrawing xdraw = (XSSFDrawing)srcdraw;
            for (XSSFShape xs : xdraw.getShapes()) 
            {
                if (xs instanceof Picture) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Picture found in XSSF");
                    pics.add((Picture)xs);

                    XSSFClientAnchor srcanchor = (XSSFClientAnchor) xs.getAnchor();
                    col = srcanchor.getCol1();
                    row = srcanchor.getRow1();

                    if(row==srcRowNum && col==colNum)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Picture to get from XSSF");
                        System.out.println("Row:"+srcRowNum);
                        System.out.println("Col:"+col);
                        byte [] bap = ((Picture) xs).getPictureData().getData();

                        CreationHelper helper = dstWB.getCreationHelper();
                        ClientAnchor dstanchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
                        dstanchor.setCol1(col); 
                        dstanchor.setCol2(col);
                        dstanchor.setRow1(dstRowNum);
                        dstanchor.setRow2(dstRowNum);
                        dstanchor.setDx1(srcanchor.getDx1());
                        dstanchor.setDx2(srcanchor.getDx2());
                        dstanchor.setDy1(srcanchor.getDy1());
                        dstanchor.setDy2(srcanchor.getDy2());
                        pictureIdx = dstWB.addPicture(bap, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                        dstdraw.createPicture(dstanchor, pictureIdx);
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dstWB.write(new FileOutputStream(new File(dstFilePath))); //Finally write the changes to the workbook
        srcWB.close();
        dstWB.close();
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```